# this kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU But i have a 64bit PC!

Tags: virtualbox, 64-bit, virtualization, cpu

I am on 64-bit Windows 8.1. I'm trying to install Ubuntu on VirtualBox. However, I get the error:

```
this kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU
Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU.
```

But my OS is 64-bit! I have `12GB DDR3 RAM`, `Intel Core i74700MQ CPU`. So why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: You have virtualbox set up to emulate only a 32 bit cpu obviously...

Answer (score 2):

Ensure CPU virtualisation is on in your `BIOS/UEFI` virtual box can give strange errors when this is off since it now allows you to run a guest OS WITHOUT this feature turned on.

you can check by downloading the `Intel Processor Identification Utility`

http://www.intel.com/support/processors/tools/piu/sb/CS-014921.htm